# Using Scipy curve_fit with external program?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

Is it possible to use curve_fit with an external program?

For example, I have a function

```
def test(a,b):
    os.system('./program a b')
    data = numpy.load('outputdata.txt')
    return data
```

which takes two variables as input variables for an external programm written in C++. This program is a simulation and creates its output into the text file. I then read the text file and return it for plotting. The one thing that is immediatly noticable is, that it does not need an X variable.

I tried running this function in curve_fit, but it will only give me the initial guess variables as a result with infinite errors.

Is this even at all possible? Could it be that the lack of an X variable is the problem? Because curve_fit needs one, I just gave it an array of [1...1], since it is not actually used.

Thx.

Comment: Using [1...1] as xdata is a bad move; they must be distinct. Try `np.linspace(0, 1, n)` where n = number of points.

Comment: If you don't have an *x* variable (or *t* or anything equivalent) you are probably not actually fitting a curve... Anyway, you can either try @Gerry's approach to use a dummy *x*, or forgo `curve_fit` and [minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) the difference between `data` and whatever target you have - both should work. One is simpler and one gives you more control. Choose whichever approach you are more comfortable with.

Comment: I actually used an array for X with different values, I just thought that [1...1] would be simpler to write.

Comment: @kazemakase is probably right about "not fitting a curve": I used a step via external calls but with leastsq and the residual function calling the external and reading the text file.